# How to document kwargs according to Numpy style docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, docstring

So, I've found posts related to other styles and I am aware of [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/docs/howto_document.html#a-guide-to-numpy-scipy-documentation) NumPy page about the documentation but I am confused. I didn't understand how to add each kwargs to the parameters section of a method. This is from the given web page:

```
def foo(var1, var2, *args, long_var_name='hi', **kwargs):
    r"""Summarize the function in one line.

    Several sentences providing an extended description. Refer to
    variables using back-ticks, e.g. `var`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    var1 : array_like
        Array_like means all those objects -- lists, nested lists, etc. --
        that can be converted to an array.  We can also refer to
        variables like `var1`.
    var2 : int
        The type above can either refer to an actual Python type
        (e.g. ``int``), or describe the type of the variable in more
        detail, e.g. ``(N,) ndarray`` or ``array_like``.
    *args : iterable
        Other arguments.
    long_var_name : {'hi', 'ho'}, optional
        Choices in brackets, default first when optional.
    **kwargs : dict
        Keyword arguments.
```

It is not clear how to add each kwargs here. I also saw this sphinx page ["Example NumPy Style Python Docstring"](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html#example-numpy-style-python-docstrings), here is the section about the kwargs:

```
def module_level_function(param1, param2=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """This is an example of a module level function.

    Function parameters should be documented in the ``Parameters`` section.
    The name of each parameter is required. The type and description of each
    parameter is optional, but should be included if not obvious.

    If \*args or \*\*kwargs are accepted,
    they should be listed as ``*args`` and ``**kwargs``.

    The format for a parameter is::

        name : type
            description

            The description may span multiple lines. Following lines
            should be indented to match the first line of the description.
            The ": type" is optional.

            Multiple paragraphs are supported in parameter
            descriptions.

    Parameters
    ----------
    param1 : int
        The first parameter.
    param2 : :obj:`str`, optional
        The second parameter.
    *args
        Variable length argument list.
    **kwargs
        Arbitrary keyword arguments.
```

Nope, I am still confused. Is it something like this?

```
"""
Dummy docstring.

Parameters
----------
**kwargs: dict
    first_kwarg: int
        This is an integer
    second_kwarg: str
        This is a string
"""
```

Comment: I have puzzled over this question myself and still don't have a great answer. On the other hand, I have also thought the following: if a specific `kwargs` key is important enough to document, perhaps I should elevate it to being a proper named keyword argument in the function signature. Something to consider.

Comment: In my experiment, need to define it first if you wanna use it. `kwargs.pop('name_var', value)`

Comment: You can [search for examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22kwargs%22+site%3Anumpy.org%2Fdoc%2Fstable%2Freference%2Fgenerated) but it seems to vary. [Ufuncs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) have their own kwargs docs, some [defer you to other docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html), some [ignore it](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.stack.html), some just [list them as if they were in the signature](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)...

Comment: For inspiration, you can look at other APIs, for example [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), which makes extensive use of kwargs (Matplotlib docs system seems to be rather complicated, I think the property tables are rendered at HTML level, but the docstring is just a list of indented items generated through introspection).

Comment: Your first link ("this") is a 404. I _believe_ you meant to put https://numpy.org/devdocs/dev/howto-docs.html instead of https://numpy.org/devdocs/docs/howto_document.html#a-guide-to-numpy-scipy-documentation (The anchor isn't necessary, as that's the top of the page.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Summary

The `**kwargs` are not typically listed in the function, but instead the final destination of the `**kwargs` is mentioned. For example:

```
**kwargs
    Instructions on how to decorate your plots.
    The keyword arguments are passed to `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot()`
```

- If there are multiple possible targets, they are all listed (see below)
- If you happen to use some automation tool to interpolate and link your documentation, then you might list the possible keyword arguments in `**kwargs` for the convenience of the end users. This kind of approach is used in matplotlib, for example. (see below)

### How and when document `**kwargs` (Numpydoc)

##### 1) When to use `**kwargs`?

First thing to note here is that `**kwargs` should be used to **pass arguments to underlying functions and methods**. If the argument inside `**kwargs` would be used in the function (and not passed down), it should be written out as normal keyword argument, instead.

##### 2) Where to put `**kwargs` decription?

The **location** of `**kwargs` description is in the `Parameters` section. Sometimes it is appropriate to list them in the [`Other Parameters`](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#other-parameters) section, but remember: *Other Parameters should only be used if a function has a large number of keyword parameters, to prevent cluttering the Parameters section.*

- `matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid` has `**kwargs` in `Parameters` section.
- `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot` has `**kwargs` in `Other Parameters` section (reasoning probably to large number of keyword arguments).

##### 3) Syntax for `**kwargs` decription

The **syntax for the description** for the `**kwargs` is, following [Numpydoc styleguide](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#parameters)

```
Parameters
----------
... (other lines)
**kwargs : sometype
     Some description on what the kwargs are
     used for.
```

or

```
Parameters
----------
... (other lines)
**kwargs
     Some description on what the kwargs are
     used for.
```

The one describing the type is more appropriate, as [[source](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#parameters)].

> *For the parameter types, be as precise as possible*

One exception for this is for example when the `**kwargs` **could be passed to one of many functions based on other parameter values**, as in [seaborn.kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot). Then, the line for the type would become too long for describing all the types and it would be cleaner to use a bullet point list, which also describes the conditions on when the `**kwargs` are forwarded to where. Eg.:

```
Parameters
----------
fill: bool or None
    If True, fill in the area under univariate density curves or between 
     bivariate contours. If None, the default depends on multiple.
**kwargs
    Other keyword arguments are passed to one of the following matplotlib 
    functions:

    * matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot() (univariate, fill=False),

    * matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between() (univariate, fill=True),

    * matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour() (bivariate, fill=False),

    * matplotlib.axes.contourf() (bivariate, fill=True).
```

You may also add listing of the **valid keyword arguments in `**kwargs`** like in  [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/5b074413ffd0a2fed8fc74850d7177bc5d6edad5/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L3211). Here is the interpolated python doc/text version:

```
Parameters
----------
... (other lines)
**kwargs : `.Line2D` properties
    Define the line properties of the grid, e.g.::

        grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)

    Valid keyword arguments are:

    Properties:
    agg_filter: a filter function, which takes a (m, n, 3) float array and a dpi value, and returns a (m, n, 3) array
    alpha: float or None
    animated: bool
    antialiased or aa: bool
    clip_box: `.Bbox`
    clip_on: bool
    clip_path: Patch or (Path, Transform) or None
    color or c: color
    contains: unknown
    dash_capstyle: {'butt', 'round', 'projecting'}
    dash_joinstyle: {'miter', '
    ... (more lines)
```

This is convenient for the user, but challenging for the developer. In matplotlib this kind of luxury is made possible with the automatization using some special documentation decorators and linking<sup>1</sup>. Manual writing of allowed kwargs will surely become a code maintenance nightmare.

##### 4) Notes related to `**kwargs` / Extended help

Some **additional info** about the `**kwargs` could be included in the [`Notes`](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#notes) section.
For example `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot` discusses marker styles, line styles and colors in the `Notes` section. <sup>[2]</sup>

---

<sup>[1]</sup> They use a `@docstring.dedent_interpd` decorator which pulls the meaning of the kwargs to the final docs. So that is happening in place of `%(Line2D:kwdoc)s`, for example. 
<sup>[2]</sup> See: `help(ax.plot)` where `ax` is instance of `matplotlib.axes.Axes`.

Answer (score 6):

Usually kwargs that need to be described in the `Parameters` section would typically be handled like other named arguments and the `**kwargs` is left unexpanded.  However, the numpy style guide also has an `Other Parameters` section than can be used for providing descriptions of kwargs without cluttering the `Parameters` section. The [style guide](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#other-parameters) describes it as:

> An optional section used to describe infrequently used parameters. It should only be used if a function has a large number of keyword parameters, to prevent cluttering the Parameters section.

The [numpydoc repo gives this example](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/blob/1668dd9f0d36d21963410dd74d8a5c7f4e706595/doc/example.py#L69):

```py
"""

    Other Parameters
    ----------------
    only_seldom_used_keyword : int, optional
        Infrequently used parameters can be described under this optional
        section to prevent cluttering the Parameters section.
    **kwargs : dict
        Other infrequently used keyword arguments. Note that all keyword
        arguments appearing after the first parameter specified under the
        Other Parameters section, should also be described under this
        section.

"""
```

So, the additional kwargs could be added as

```py
"""

    Other Parameters
    ----------------
    first_kwarg: int
        This is an integer
    second_kwarg: str
        This is a string
    **kwargs : dict
        Other infrequently used keyword arguments.

"""
```

Comment: This answer is OK: if you know the keyword on the param, it should be listed at the end of positional params. `**kwargs` is for all the other stuff, like params that will be forwarded.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I say in the first sentence, but offer the `Other Parameters` as an alternative to keep from cluttering the `Parameters` section.